# Bar-end shifters with Pinion C12 gearbox

Tags: shifter, compatibility

I read that the Pinion is indexed at the gearbox. Does this mean I can use an old school bar-end shifter in place of the rotary shifter?

Answer (score 1):

This information alone wouldn't be sufficient, you also need to know the pull-ratios (amount of cable movement required to change gears), that is not published. But Pinion shifters use 2 cables, so it's very unlikely that a conventional bar-end shifter would work.